# Find all $f:Z→Z$ which satisfy $f(m+n)(f(m)−f(n))=f(m−n)(f(m)+f(n))$

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

**question** -

Find all $f:Z→Z$ which satisfy the conditions $f(1)=1$ and
$f(m+n)(f(m)−f(n))=f(m−n)(f(m)+f(n))$
for all integers $m,n$

**my try** -

I first Prove that $f(0)=0$ and hence $f(n)(f(n)+f(−n))=0$ for all $n∈Z$. Changing $n$ to $−n$, i conclude that $f(n)+ f(−n)=0$. so hence i get that f is odd function.....

Taking $m=2$ and $n=1$, I conclude that $(f(3)−1)(f(2)−1)=2$.

This gives me four possibilities:

(a)$f(2)=2$, $f(3)=3$;

(b)$f(2)=3$, $f(3)=2$ ;

(c)$f(2)=0$, $f(3)=−1$

and (d) $f(2)=−1$,$f(3)=0$.

I Showed that (a) leads to $f(n)=n$ for all n and (b) is not possible by checking some values .....but i am not able to find $f$ in cases (c) and (d).....

any help will be appreciated

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case c)**

Taking $n=1$ we get
$$\begin{align}
f(2+1) (f(2)-f(1)) &= f(2-1) (f(2)+f(1)) \implies f(3) = -1 \\
f(3+1) (f(3)-f(1)) &= f(3-1) (f(3)+f(1)) \implies f(4) = 0 \\
f(4+1) (f(4)-f(1)) &= f(4-1) (f(4)+f(1)) \implies f(5) = 1 \\
\vdots \\
f(2k) = 0,\ &f(2k+1) = (-1)^k
\end{align}$$
This result can even be written as one formula: $f(n) = \sin\frac{n\pi}{2}.$

Case d should now be easy.

---

**Induction proof**

We know that $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1,$ $f(2) = 0,$ $f(3) = -1.$

Now suppose that for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have 
$f(4k+0) = 0,$ $f(4k+1) = 1,$ $f(4k+2) = 0,$ $f(4k+3) = -1.$
Then,
$$
f((4k+3)+1) (f(4k+3) - f(1)) = f((4k+3)-1) (f(4k+3) + f(1)) \\
f(4k+4) (-1 - 1) = 0 (-1 + 1) \\
\therefore f(4(k+1)+0) = 0. \\
$$
$$
f((4k+4)+1) (f(4k+4) - f(1)) = f((4k+4)-1) (f(4k+4) + f(1)) \\
f(4k+5) (0 - 1) = (-1) (0 + 1) \\
\therefore f(4(k+1)+1) = 1. \\
$$
$$
f((4k+5)+1) (f(4k+5) - f(1)) = f((4k+5)-1) (f(4k+5) + f(1)) \\
f(4k+6) (-1 - 1) = 0 (-1 + 1) \\
\therefore f(4(k+1)+2) = 0. \\
$$
$$
f((4k+6)+1) (f(4k+6) - f(1)) = f((4k+6)-1) (f(4k+6) + f(1)) \\
f(4k+7) (0 - 1) = 1 (0 + 1) \\
\therefore f(4(k+1)+3) = -1. \\
$$

Since the assertions $f(4k+0) = 0,$ $f(4k+1) = 1,$ $f(4k+2) = 0,$ $f(4k+3) = -1$ are valid for $k=0$ and the validity for any $k$ implies validity for $k+1$ we get that they are valid for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_0.$

How about negative $k$? We can use that $f$ is odd. Let $k<0.$ Then $-k\geq 0$ so
$$
f(4k+0) = -f(-(4k+0)) = -f(4(-k-1)+4) = -0 = 0, \\
f(4k+1) = -f(-(4k+1)) = -f(4(-k-1)+3) = -(-1) = 1, \\
f(4k+2) = -f(-(4k+2)) = -f(4(-k-1)+2) = -0 = 0, \\
f(4k+3) = -f(-(4k+3)) = -f(4(-k-1)+1) = -1.
$$
Thus the asserted formulas are also valid for $k<0.$

Comment: but how to prove that $f(2k)=0$ and $f(2k+1)=(-1)^k$....??? using induction ??

Comment: can you tell me what should we substitute. because i am not able to get right substitution..

Comment: Induction should work.

Comment: ok,thanks.......

Comment: @User88463. I have now added an induction proof.